# MS office incorrect visualization, blurry menu

Tags: outlook, ms-office

Can someone help me with blurried menu in MS office Windows 10? 
Tried MS Office 2016/2019 by re-installation, but every time gettting same picture, one of panel is blurred. Functional is working fine.
[Blurred panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snOdm.png)
[Blurred body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbLN0.png)

Situation repeated for Outlook and Excel
Note: Outlook after re-installation saves login, so, perhaps, i need full remove of all MS Office components? If yes, how to do that?

Comment: That looks like a problem with the graphic driver.  I'd search around to see if you can find a different driver for your graphics system.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be because of second monitor, issue solved with next steps:
1) Open any Microsoft Office program.
2) Click on the File tab in the upper left.
3) Select Options from the left navigation menu.
4)In the popup window, select Advanced from the left navigation menu.
5) Scroll down to the Display section and check the box to "Disable hardware graphics acceleration".
6) Click OK, close all Office applications, and restart.